# How to append data in android (each data in new line)

Tags: android, file-io, fileoutputstream

I am making a bookmark for web browser app this code is saving and loading the data but it is not appending data in new line...every time i am pressing the button it is overwriting previous data ..I want that every time i call `bookmarkload();` method in main activity it should save data in new line instead of overwriting it..Please help me as i am new to android tell what line to enter where..so that it start appending data..Thanks in advance ..please give answer in detail if possible.

```
public class Bookmark {

FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fis = null;

public void bookmarksave(Context context,String FILENAME,String data){

    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, 0);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String bookmarkload(Context context,String FILENAME){

    String collected =null;
    try{
        fis =context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
            collected = new String(dataArray);
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return collected;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
```

Try this one... new data will be appended in new line..

Comment: @jazz: u can upvote my answer if u found it useful so that it can be helpful to others also. thank u...

Comment: it is working but whenever i am saving my first bookmark it is saving it 2 times..like for example url is http://www.facebook.com it is saving www.facebook.comwww.facebook.com and then after entering it thrid time it is saving it alone in next line like www.facebook.com ..

Answer (score 0):

change the Line `fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, 0);` to

```
fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

This will open your file in append mode, instead of the default (override) mode.

You should also add a new line, otherwise you continue in the same line as before:

```
fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
```

Comment: it is working but whenever i am saving my first bookmark it is saving it 2 times..like for example url is http://www.facebook.com it is saving www.facebook.comwww.facebook.com and then after entering it thrid time it is saving it alone in next line like www.facebook.com ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to save your bookmark.It's very convenience.And if you want to use File to store them.You can use `new FileOutputStream(filename,true)`  ,true means bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.